# How does the $I$-$V$ curve for bulk metal look like?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, semiconductor-physics, electronics

For semiconductors, the current (I) vs. voltage (V) relationship is as shown in the picture below.

[image]

As we increase the applied voltage, the electron-hole pairs generate increases too, so we see an almost linear increase in current.
Now if we consider metals, how will current behave if we increase voltage? Metals are full of electrons, so on increasing V, will it have any effect on I at all? I feel, the curve might be like this:

[image]

Is it correct?

Comment: Have you heard of Ohm’s law?

Comment: So by Ohm's law,will the I-V curve for metals will be a linear one like in semiconductors?

Comment: For metals, what is happening when we increase voltage? There is no scene of electrons being drawn out from any valence band here

Comment: Can you clarify what your first diagram shows? It looks like the graph for a PN junction rather than for a single semiconductor.

Comment: @JohnRennie, Uh, yes it's of a PN junction. Doesn't this same curve apply to all semiconductors in general? In a semiconductor also first a lil voltage is required for the electrons to gain enough energy to cross the band gap, and then the conduction starts.

Comment: @ShaonaBose no. The form of the VI curve for a diode is due to formation of a depletion layer at the junction. If you just have a chunk of semiconductor then it behaves like a regular ohmic conductor - well, that is until you reach field strengths strong enough to cause dielectric breakdown but that's far higher than normally used in circuits.

Comment: @JohnRennie Okay, so a normal semiconductor would behave like an ohmic conductor. The I-V curve would just be linear without any 'knee voltage' like in a PN junction, right?

Comment: @ShaonaBose yes

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's law applies to metals.

In fact, Ohm developed the law through investigation of metals, not semiconductors, insulators, or other types of materials.

> how will the I-V curve look like?

The I-V curve for a metallic conductor, or any other Ohmic conductor, is a straight line through the origin.

(In practical measurements, you might find the line is not perfectly straight, due to Joule heating and the material resistivity varying with temperature)

Comment: But in the comments following my question, it says Ohm's law applies to semiconductors. I am confused again. Okay then how will the I-V curve look like?

Comment: @ShaonaBose, Where did I say Ohm's law doesn't apply to semiconductors?

Comment: @ShaonaBose, in any case, you posted another question about semiconductors, so you should look there for answers addressing semiconductors.